# Play local audio on remote computer (Linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, audio

Is it possible to transfer audio from my local computer to a remote one, eg through SSH?

I know this transfers mic to other computer

```
dd if=/dev/dsp | ssh -c arcfour -C username@host dd of=/dev/dsp
```

but as I didn't invent that my self I honestly don't know how to apply that for playing music?

Comment: Do you want to transfer the audio file, or play it through the other computer's speakers?  Playing it appears to be the intention, but I wanted to clarify before suggesting things.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to play it through your computer's speakers (as opposed to the remote computer's speakers)? This question on superuser.com may shed some light on it. [Forwarding audio like X in SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/231920/forwarding-audio-like-x-in-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use mpd for remote playing, but it works like this: you set up the mpd server on one computer, where your mp3/ogg collection sits, and then you can use a mpd client (such as sonata) on another computer where you play the music.

It all depends on where you want to *control* the playback - on the server (where the music library sits) or on the client (where you have the speakers connected). If you want  control on the client, mpd is your buddy.

If, on the other hand you just want a dummy pc with speakers connected and you want to control what's playing from another pc with the music library, then you should try icecast I think, although I haven't tried it yet.

Or, a third way, you have the library and speakers on one pc, and just control everything from a different pc. This would be best done by an mpd config where the client and the server are on one pc (the one with the library and the speakers) and you just ssh into it and use a console client to just control the music (console mpd clients: mpc, ncmpcpp - my favorite).

I can think of another config: one pc to control the music, one pc with the speakers and a third pc (NAS most likely) which holds the music library in the network - this is easily doable with mpd too.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit dated, but in 2018 on a Linux system, the simplest method would be to use Pulseaudio: Either directly connect to the remote Pulseaudio server, or make a local sink that is connected to a remote source (`module-tunnel-*`). Other options are to use audio streaming protocols inside or outside Pulseaudio, like NTP (`module-rtp-`) or ROAP (Apple AirPort, `module-roap-*`).

More details for the setup for the various alternatives are e.g. described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/). Also see the Pulseaudio [module](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) page.