# Nested ssh command forwarding

Tags: ssh, streaming, sox

In general I could realtime listen audio on the remote computer as:

```
ssh me@gate rec -t mp3 - | play -
```

e.g. on the computer named `gate` I could execute the command `rec` (or `sox`) and the audio-stream is transferred over the network, so I could replay it real-time via the `play` (or `sox`) command.

This works OK, especially because I have password-less access to the `gate` from my notebook (using `authorized_keys & authorized_keys2`).

But my topology is:

```
+----+  internet   +------+  lan   +----------+
| my | ----------> | gate | -----> | internal |
+----+             +------+        +----------+
```

and I need execute the `rec` in the `internal` comp and it's `stdout` should be piped to the `play` command in the `my` computer.

So, when I cascading (nesting) the `ssh`s like:

```
ssh -t me@gate ssh me@internal rec -t mp3 -
```

(note the `-t` for `ssh`)

- so, the `gate` is accessed password-less
- on the `gate` is executed the second (nested) `ssh`
- so the `internal` asks me for the password (`-t`)
- and when I enter the password, the `internal` correctly starts the `rec` command
- and I could watch the received binary data-garbage on my local terminal.

Unfortunately, this doesn't works when I trying to pipe to the `play`, e.g. this

```
ssh -t me@gate ssh me@internal rec -t mp3 - | play -
```

doesn't works, because the `Password:` string got redirected (e.g. I not prompted for the password), and the `play` got confused.

Setting up password-less access between the `me@gate` -> `me@internal` probably could solve the problem, but I **don't want** this - I want manually enter the password to the `internal` comp.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `-t` doesn't ask for a password... "_Disable pseudo-terminal allocation._"

Comment: Side note: I think you may have the knowledge to answer [this old question](https://superuser.com/q/492640/432690).

Answer (score 1):

I assume `internal` listens on the standard `22` port.

First build a tunnel:

```
ssh -N -L localhost:2222:internal:22 me@gate
# you can put it to background with &
```

Then connect through the tunnel. This connection will end up at `internal`:

```
ssh -p 2222 me@localhost rec -t mp3 - | play -
```

You should be asked for your password to `internal` despite the pipe being used.

---

`ssh -L …` is explained in [my answer to another question](https://superuser.com/a/1285060/432690).

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the password prompt doesn't get in the way if your laptop is able to access `internal` directly?

If so, have a play with the `ProxyCommand` configuration option.

Put something like this in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host internal-via-gate
    User me
    Hostname internal
    Port 22
    ProxyCommand ssh gate nc %h %p
```

This should allow you to simply run `ssh internal-via-gate`, as if you were connecting directly.

---

If not, then maybe consider port forwarding:

```
Host internal-via-gate
    User me
    Hostname internal
    Port 22
    ProxyCommand ssh gate nc %h %p
    LocalForward 27015 localhost:27015
```

Then, connect and authenticate (`ssh internal-via-gate`).

Once you're logged in, run:

- `rec -t mp3 - | nc -l 27015` on the remote, and
- `nc localhost 27015 | play -` on the local machine.