# SSH forwarding audio in Debian 12 KDE

Tags: linux, ssh, audio, debian, kde

Systems:

1. X86_64
   Debian 12 bookworm KDE
   AND
   Debian 11 bullseye KDE
2. Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB
   Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) (official port of Debian Bookworm)

PROBLEM:
I have an X86_64 receiving audio from my Raspberry Pi via "ssh -X".
Example: ssh -X Bill@192.168.0.111 firefox https://www.youtube.com
(I'm just using firefox as an example here.)

Audio works for this arrangement if Debian 11 (Bullseye) KDE is installed on the X86_64 receiving machine.
Unfortunately, audio FAILS (no sound) if Debian 12 (Bookworm) KDE is installed on the X86_64 receiving machine.

I followed the setup instructions in:
[Forwarding audio like X in SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/231920/forwarding-audio-like-x-in-ssh)
(Equivalent to adding "load-module module-native-protocol-tcp" to "/etc/pulse/default.pa" on the X86_64 machine, then rebooting.)
These instructions work for Debian 11 (Bullseye) KDE on the X86_64 machine,
but fail for the Debian 12 (Bookworm) KDE X86_64 machine.

I understand that Debian 11 (Bullseye) KDE is using pulse-audio;
while Debian 12 (Bookworm) KDE is using a hybrid of pulse-audio and pipewire.
I've tried installing "wireplumber", "pipewire-pulse", etc.
But I've failed to get audio forwarding from the Raspberry Pi to the X86_64 machine with Debian 12.

I would appreciate any guidance.
Thank you for the help.